# How exactly do I get the an attribute's value in a Spring MVC Validator and add a custom validator for it

Tags: validation, jsp, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I'm not quite sure if I've phrased my question correctly but here goes. I have a form where I take in the details such as *Start Date*, *End Date* *Name* etc. To validate these details, I have a validator where I use the `ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace()` method which is pretty standard. Suppose I want to check whether a field called *name* is empty, I can simply do `ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "name", "required")`.

However, suppose I want to check if the Start Date and End Date are correctly entered. That is, Start date should be lesser than the End date. How do I get the values of these start date and end date the user entered *inside the validator*. Also, How do I validate it because `rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace()` doesn't quite fit the criteria. I'm pasting the relevant code for my View Page, Controller and Validator Below:

**JSP VIEW page**

```
<form id="form1" method="post" class="form-container">
    <form:errors path="*" cssClass="errorblock" element="div"/>
    <ul class="list-styled">
        <li>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <spring:bind path="cohortmodule.name">
                    <h4><spring:message code="cohort.cohortname"/> </h4>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" id="name" size="25" value="${status.value}"/>
                    <c:if test="${status.errorMessage != ''}"><span class="error">${status.errorMessage}</span></c:if>
                </spring:bind>
            </fieldset>
        </li>

        <li>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <spring:bind path="cohortmodule.startDate">
                   <h4> <spring:message code="cohort.startdate"/> </h4>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="startDate" size="10"
                           id="startDate" value="${status.value}"/><i style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 0.8em;">(<openmrs:message
                        code="general.format"/>: <openmrs:datePattern/>)</i>
                    <c:if test="${status.errorMessage != ''}"><span class="error">${status.errorMessage}</span></c:if>
                </spring:bind>
            </fieldset>
        </li>

        <li>
            <fieldset class="form-group">
                <spring:bind path="cohortmodule.endDate">
                    <h4><spring:message code="cohort.enddate"/> </h4>
                    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="endDate" size="10" onFocus="showCalendar(this,60)"
                           id="endDate" value="${status.value}"/><i style="font-weight: normal; font-size: 0.8em;">(<openmrs:message
                        code="general.format"/>: <openmrs:datePattern/>)</i>
                    <c:if test="${status.errorMessage != ''}"><span class="error">${status.errorMessage}</span></c:if>
                </spring:bind>
            </fieldset>
        </li>

        <div class="button-container">
            <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Save and Skip" id="submit"/><br/><br/>
        </div>

        <div class="button-container">
            <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Next" id="next" name="next">
        </div>

    </ul>

    <br/>
    <br/>

</form>
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
package org.openmrs.module.cohort.web.controller;
import org.openmrs.Location;
import org.openmrs.Patient;
import org.openmrs.api.LocationService;
import org.openmrs.api.PatientService;
import org.openmrs.api.context.Context;
import org.openmrs.module.cohort.*;
import org.openmrs.module.cohort.api.CohortService;
import org.openmrs.web.WebConstants;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * The main controller.
 */
@Controller
public class AddCohortController {

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("addCohortValidator")
    private Validator validator;
    List<Patient> list1 = new ArrayList();
    Set set1 = new HashSet();

    @ModelAttribute
    private void addReferenceData(ModelMap model) {
        List<String> cohorttype = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> cohortprg = new ArrayList<String>();
        LocationService service = Context.getLocationService();
        List<Location> formats = service.getAllLocations();
        model.addAttribute("locations", formats);
        CohortService service1 = Context.getService(CohortService.class);
        List<CohortType> list1 = service1.getAllCohortTypes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            CohortType c = list1.get(i);
            cohorttype.add(c.getName());
        }
        List<CohortProgram> list2 = service1.findCohortProg();
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
            CohortProgram a = list2.get(j);
            cohortprg.add(a.getName());
        }
        model.addAttribute("formats", cohorttype);
        model.addAttribute("formats1", cohortprg);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/module/cohort/addCohort", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public void manage(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("cohortmodule", new CohortM());
        List<String> cohorttype = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> cohortprg = new ArrayList<String>();
        LocationService service = Context.getLocationService();
        List<Location> formats = service.getAllLocations();
        model.addAttribute("locations", formats);
        CohortService service1 = Context.getService(CohortService.class);
        List<CohortType> list1 = service1.getAllCohortTypes();
        for (int i = 0; i < list1.size(); i++) {
            CohortType c = list1.get(i);
            cohorttype.add(c.getName());
        }
        List<CohortProgram> list2 = service1.findCohortProg();
        for (int j = 0; j < list2.size(); j++) {
            CohortProgram a = list2.get(j);
            cohortprg.add(a.getName());
        }
        model.addAttribute("formats", cohorttype);
        model.addAttribute("formats1", cohortprg);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "module/cohort/addCohort.form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String onSubmit(WebRequest request, HttpSession httpSession, HttpServletRequest request1,
                           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "name") String cohort_name,
                           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "description") String description,
                           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "startDate") String start_date,
                           @RequestParam(required = false, value = "endDate") String end_date,
                           @ModelAttribute("cohortmodule") CohortM cohortmodule, BindingResult errors, ModelMap model) throws Exception {
        CohortType cohort1 = new CohortType();
        CohortProgram prg = new CohortProgram();
        Location loc = new Location();
        String cohort_program = request.getParameter("format1");
        String cohort_type_name = request.getParameter("format");
        String location = request.getParameter("location");
        java.util.Date startDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(start_date);
        java.util.Date endDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(end_date);
        System.out.println(startDate + " " + endDate);
        CohortService departmentService = Context.getService(CohortService.class);
        if (!Context.isAuthenticated()) {
            errors.reject("Required");
        }
        this.validator.validate(cohortmodule, errors);
        if (errors.hasErrors()) {
            System.out.println("BR has errors: " + errors.getErrorCount());
            System.out.println(errors.getAllErrors());
            return "/module/cohort/addCohort";
        } else {
            List<CohortProgram> list2 = departmentService.findCohortProgram(cohort_program);
            List<CohortType> cohorttype1 = departmentService.findCohortType(cohort_type_name);
            LocationService service = Context.getLocationService();
            List<Location> formats = service.getLocations(location);
            for (int j = 0; j < formats.size(); j++) {
                loc = formats.get(j);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < cohorttype1.size(); i++) {
                cohort1 = cohorttype1.get(i);
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < list2.size(); a++) {
                prg = list2.get(a);
            }
            cohortmodule.setCohortProgram(prg);
            cohortmodule.setClocation(loc);
            cohortmodule.setCohortType(cohort1);
            cohortmodule.setStartDate(startDate);
            cohortmodule.setEndDate(endDate);
            departmentService.saveCohort(cohortmodule);
            httpSession.setAttribute(WebConstants.OPENMRS_MSG_ATTR, "insertion success");
            model.addAttribute("locations", formats);
            model.addAttribute("formats", cohorttype1);
            model.addAttribute("formats1", list2);
            model.addAttribute("cohortmodule", cohortmodule);
            model.addAttribute("startDate", startDate);
            model.addAttribute("endDate", endDate);
            if ("Next".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getParameter("next"))) {
                departmentService.saveCohort(cohortmodule);
                httpSession.setAttribute(WebConstants.OPENMRS_MSG_ATTR, "insertion success");
                String redirectUrl = "/module/cohort/addCohortAttributes.form?ca=" + cohortmodule.getCohortId();
                return "redirect:" + redirectUrl;
            }

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

**VALIDATOR**

```
    package org.openmrs.module.cohort.web.validator;

import org.openmrs.module.cohort.CohortM;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.ValidationUtils;
import org.springframework.validation.Validator;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

@Component
@Qualifier("addCohortValidator")
public class AddCohortValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> arg0) {
        return arg0.equals(CohortM.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object arg0, Errors arg1) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "name", "required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "startDate", "required");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "endDate", "required");

    }
}
```

Could someone please guide me as to how to proceed? Thanks